# What does it "-1" in the loop mean

Tags: python, for-loop

What does it "-1" in the loop mean

```
CAPACITY = 10
buffer = [-1 for i in range(CAPACITY)]
```

Comment: It's not a loop, though. It's called a "list comprehension"

Answer (score 4):

That is the element of the list that will get created as part of the list-comprehension.

```
>>> l = [-1 for _ in range(5)]
>>> l
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
>>> l[1] = 2
>>> l
[-1, 2, -1, -1, -1]
```

This specific example could also be written as `[-1] * CAPACITY`.

```
>>> l = [-1] * 5
>>> l
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
>>> l[1] = 2
>>> l
[-1, 2, -1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but it is not the same thing in general though (similar enough for immutable objects, I'll admit)

Comment: @user2390182 but in this particular case it accomplishes exactly the same so I would consider it to be _the same thing_

Answer (score 2):

This is a list comprehension - when expanded out it would be equivalent to:

```
buffer = []
for i in range(CAPACITY):
    buffer.append(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a List Comprehension.

You are basically declaring a list of `CAPACITY` size with a for loop, all elements of that list will have a value of `-1`.

If you `print(buffer)`, you will get the following output:

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```